# Why is this code returning a runtime error in line 8

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @return {boolean}
 */
var containsDuplicate = function(nums) {
    let base = nums.length;
    let diff = [...new Set(nums)].length;
    if base !== diff return true // <--- this line
    else {
        return false
    }
};
```

the console is saying there is an error with base in the 8th line. This is Leetcode question #217.

I've tried the following:

changing spelling from length and legnth
tried changing variablenames
tried switching return true and false
and changing the equation to !== instead of ====

Comment: Hint: In JavaScript it's always `if (...)`, brackets not optional. This isn't Python or Ruby where those rules don't apply. When you're stuck on a problem like this, remember there's a great [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) at the MDN site. In this case searching for "mdn if" pulls up the answer quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is the syntax of if-else condition:

```
 if(some condition){
   do that;
 }else{
   do that;
}
```

in your case it should look like that:
if (base !== diff)
return true
else {
return false
}
and make sure when you use !== you checks also data type
I hope that was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

I forgot to put () after the if on line 8. Thanks to @tadman.

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @return {boolean}
 */
var containsDuplicate = function(nums) {
    let base = nums.length;
    let diff = [...new Set(nums)].length;
    if (base !== diff) return true
    else {
        return false
    }
};
```